# Entering credit-card only once for phone orders (admin screen)

Tags: magento-1.8, payment-gateway, edit-order

We like to take phone orders using the admin interface.

Unfortunately it can be a real pain because we have to re-enter the credit card information everytime the customer decides to change the order.  This happens frequently with phone sales.

Ideally, we would like to enter the payment information once, and only once, for an order.   Then, if the customer wants something different or changes their mind, we can just recalculate the total without re-entering the credit card.

The particular credit card gateway extension we are using says "that is just how Magento works" but the usability is terrible, and results in a poor customer experience.

Anyone figure out how to enter the credit card information only once for an order and be able to continue to

Comment: how can you define an order is phone order

Comment: Nothing defines it as a phone order, I'm simply referring to orders that are entered through the admin interface rather than the cart front-end.

Comment: I found there are authorize.net extensions which support 'CIM' which solve this problem, but that is overkill.   I would prefer that the order creation page simply didn't clear the credit card information each time the order is edited.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to use payment gate extension which allows to save Credit Card details on payment gate site instead of saving this in Magento. Saving this in Magento would likely break PCI DSS security standards, it's not recommended.

At least these payment gates support saving card on their side and provide ready to use Magento extension:

- Braintree
- Authorize.net CIM

Comment: Thanks, that is the way I was leaning...  a tokenizing payment gateway.   IMHO a better solution would be if Magento's order editing screen was more 'AJAX' so it didn't have to round-trip and retain the credit-card info at the server.

Comment: I believe with any of these extensions it will work that way. When placing phone order you should be able to select one card from the list. As far as I remember it will display obscured card number (with some last chars there) and will allow you to place order using one of cards stored on gateway side.

Comment: You can also look at Stripe.com, they dont offer a Magento extension themself, but there are a few available that offer saving the tokenized van d so you can charge updated orders.